# Command to automatically start new row

Tags: macros, longtable, multicolumn

I need not trivial help.

I have a command with parameters. This command fills in and prints the following table:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{3.2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.3cm}|} \hline

Some Text: & \multicolumn{3}{p{12.5cm}|}{ \raggedright {#1}} \\\\ \hline  

.....

Some Text: & {\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{#7}} & {\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{#8}} & {\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{#9}}  \hline

\end{longtable}
```

I need some command which user will set into cell (`#1` parameter).

I mean: for example user write text into cell, and between text user call command e.g. `\GoToNewRow`.
Then current row should be finished and further text put into the following row.

This command should do something like

1. close current multicolumn
2. make `\\ \hline`
3. the further cell leave empty
4. open new `\multicolumn` and set into the further text.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, in case comment under my answer. `12.5cm` for the multicolumn goes out of the page so I reduced it to `7.5cm`.

If you want to leave the first cell of each row empty, then just delete "some text:" from the `\newcommand`.

[image: figure 1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\newrow}[1]{
    Some text: & \multicolumn{3}{p{7.5cm}|}{ \raggedright {#1}} \\ \hline
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{longtable}{|p{3.2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.3cm}|} \hline

        \newrow{hello}
        \newrow{this}
        \newrow{is}
        \newrow{a}
        \newrow{new}
        \newrow{row}

\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```